# Как сериализовать java объект в json со вложенными классами с помощью jackson?

Tags: java, json, jackson

Есть класс Snapshot с двумя вложенными классами - Person и Department:

```
public class Snapshot {
    
    public Snapshot() {}
    public Snapshot(String diffId, String organization, Person person, Departments departmentrs) {
        this.diffId = diffId;
        this.organization = organization;
        this.person = person;
        this.departments = departments;
    }

    private String diffId;  
    private String organization;
    
    @JsonProperty("person")
    private Person person;
    
    @JsonProperty("departments")
    private Departments departments;

    public String getDiffId() {
        return diffId;
    }
    public void setDiffId(String diffId) {
        this.diffId = diffId;
    }
    public String getOrganization() {
        return organization;
    }
    public void setOrganization(String organization) {
        this.organization = organization;
    }
    public Person getPerson() {
        return person;
    }
    public void setPerson(Person person) {
        this.person = person;
    }
    public Departments getDepartments() {
        return departments;
    }
    public void setDepartments(Departments departments) {
        this.departments = departments;
    }
    public class Person {
        public Person() {};
        public Person(String id, String fullName, String mobilePhone, List list, List<?> allids, 
                Boolean general, Boolean isWho, Boolean rvz) {
            this.id = id;
            this.fullName = fullName;
            this.mobilePhone = mobilePhone;
            this.appontments = list;
            this.allids = allids;
            this.general = general;
            this.isWho = isWho;
            this.rvz = rvz;
            
        }
        

        private String id;
        private String fullName;
        private String mobilePhone;
        private List appontments; // Set of appointments
        private List<?> allids;
        private String name;
        private Boolean general;
        private Boolean isWho;
        private Boolean rvz;
        public String getId() {
            return id;
        }
        public void setId(String id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
        public String getFullName() {
            return fullName;
        }
        public void setFullName(String fullName) {
            this.fullName = fullName;
        }
        public String getMobilePhone() {
            return mobilePhone;
        }
        public void setMobilePhone(String mobilePhone) {
            this.mobilePhone = mobilePhone;
        }
        public List getAppontments() {
            return appontments;
        }
        public void setAppontments(List appontments) {
            this.appontments = appontments;
        }
        public List<?> getAllids() {
            return allids;
        }
        public void setAllids(List<?> allids) {
            this.allids = allids;
        }
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
        public Boolean getGeneral() {
            return general;
        }
        public void setGeneral(Boolean general) {
            this.general = general;
        }
        public Boolean getIsWho() {
            return isWho;
        }
        public void setIsWho(Boolean isWho) {
            this.isWho = isWho;
        }
        public Boolean getRvz() {
            return rvz;
        }
        public void setRvz(Boolean rvz) {
            this.rvz = rvz;
        }
        
        

    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "IDocsSnapshot [diffId=" + diffId + ", organization=" + organization + "]";
    }
    
    public class Departments {
        public Departments() {};
        public Departments(String id, String departmentName, String allids, String parentName, String shortName,
                String index) {
            this.id = id;
            this.departmentName = departmentName;
            this.allids = allids;
            this.parentName = parentName;
            this.shortName = shortName;
            this.index = index;
        }

        private String id;
        private String departmentName;
        private String allids;
        private String parentName;
        private String shortName;
        private String index;
        public String getId() {
            return id;
        }
        public void setId(String id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
        public String getDepartmentName() {
            return departmentName;
        }
        public void setDepartmentName(String departmentName) {
            this.departmentName = departmentName;
        }
        public String getAllids() {
            return allids;
        }
        public void setAllids(String allids) {
            this.allids = allids;
        }
        public String getParentName() {
            return parentName;
        }
        public void setParentName(String parentName) {
            this.parentName = parentName;
        }
        public String getShortName() {
            return shortName;
        }
        public void setShortName(String shortName) {
            this.shortName = shortName;
        }
        public String getIndex() {
            return index;
        }
        public void setIndex(String index) {
            this.index = index;
        }
        
        

    }
        

}
```

Как преобразовать объекты данного класса в json, с помощью jackson? Какие аннотации нужно подключить?

Comment: Я для подобной задачи использовал либу Gson, погугли, может поможет.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский нужно написать ещё о том, как сериализовать в Json с помощью разных библиотек ;)

Comment: @AlexChermenin да, была у меня такая мысль. возможно как-нибудь...

Answer (score 1):

Для сериализации Java объектов в `JSON` с помощью библиотеки `Jackson` необходимо выполнить следующие шаги:

1. Добавить библиотеку `Jackson` в проект.
   Если вы используете `Maven`, добавьте зависимость `Jackson` в файл `pom.xml`:

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
       <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
       <version>2.13.1</version>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. Создать класс, который нужно сериализовать в `JSON`. Для примера создадим следующие классы:

   ```
     public class Person {
       private String name;
       private int age;
       private Address address;

       // конструкторы, геттеры и сеттеры
   }

   public class Address {
       private String city;
       private String street;

       // конструкторы, геттеры и сеттеры
   }
   ```
3. Создать экземпляр класса `ObjectMapper`, который будет выполнять сериализацию.

   ```
   ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
   ```
4. Вызвать метод `writeValueAsString()` для сериализации объекта в JSON.

   ```
   Person person = new Person("Vasiliy Pumpkin", 30, new Address("Какой-то город", 
                              "Какой-то адрес"));
   String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(person);
   ```

В этом примере мы использовали класс `ObjectMapper` для сериализации объекта Person в `JSON`. Поле `address` в классе `Person` является объектом класса `Address`, поэтому `Jackson` автоматически сериализует его вложенные поля в соответствующие поля JSON-объекта.

В результате выполнения кода переменная json будет содержать следующую строку JSON:

```
{
    "name": "Vasiliy Pumpkin",
    "age": 30,
    "address": {
        "city": "Какой-то город",
        "street": "Какой-то адрес"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если надо отправить JSON на морду из контроллена, то просто запихни его в return, в методе который аннотирован вот так

```
@GetMapping(path = URL_SEARCH, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public List<UserDto> search...
```

А если надо просто JSON объект (не понимаю правда зачем с ним мудрить в Java), то вот так:

```
ObjectWriter ow = new ObjectMapper().writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();
String json = ow.writeValueAsString(object);
```